# Mensa test - lines between vertices of a 3x3 grid

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

I took a Mensa practice test, which is found on the r/mensa subreddit. Somebody claimed that this was the most accurate Mensa practice test. The link to this test is http://www.mensa.fi/test/test_frameset.html. I came across a question in the test which I wasn't able to solve:

[image]

I could not find out a pattern that governs how lines are added to the figure. Help in this problem is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each step,

> all vertical lines are copied right one cell; all horizontal lines are copied down one cell; all -diagonal lines are copied ↙ one cell; and all /-diagonal lines are copied ↘ one cell.

So the answer is

> E; the big vertical line is copied right one, and the diagonal line is copied ↘-wards.